# jQuery onChange only running once

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have jQuery function in a Wordpress Woo form that basically based on the dropdown fills in certain fields, the jQuery only executes once however.
The code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // Your code in here
  jQuery(document).on('change', '#billing_complex_name', function() {
    myFunc();
  })

  function myFunc() {
    // your function code
    var complex_name = jQuery('#billing_complex_name').val();

    var suburb = jQuery('#billing_suburb').val();

    if (complex_name == 'eldogleneast') {
      jQuery("#billing_suburb").val('ELD');
      jQuery('#billing_postcode').val('0157');
    } else if (complex_name == 'Reldoglen') {
      jQuery("#billing_suburb").val('LPN');
      jQuery('#billing_postcode').val('0133');
    } else if (complex_name == 'eldin') {
      jQuery("#billing_suburb").val('STK');
      jQuery('#billing_postcode').val('2147');
      jQuery("#billing_complex_address").val('Lion St');
    } else if (complex_name == 'elm') {
      jQuery("#billing_suburb").val('ELD');
      jQuery('#billing_postcode').val('0147');
      jQuery("#billing_complex_address").val('Lor Ave');
    }
  }
})
```

How do I get it to always run onChange not just the once.

Comment: please add your HTML too how are you calling method?

Comment: Add your HTML code too then We can see... what are you using for change event like `select` or `radio` or `checkbox`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'it only executes once'

Comment: @RaeeshAlam A Select statement

Comment: @HowardE Upon first time selection from the select box it will change the values of the associated input boxes, trying after wards no change will occur

Comment: @RawalD You can check my snippet as example and brief explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 1st time select working and 2nd time not then need to `reset value of select` on `mouseenter` event like in my snippet code.

Don't need to write `document ready statement` For both `static` and `dynamic` select changes.
**Something like this.**

> jQuery(document).on('change', 'select', function (e) {
> // do something 
> });

I hope below snippet will help you a lot.

```js
function myFunc(getvalue) {
    var complex_name = getvalue;
    if (complex_name == 'eldogleneast') {
        jQuery("#billing_suburb").val('ELD');
        jQuery('#billing_postcode').val('0157');
    } else if (complex_name == 'Reldoglen') {
        jQuery("#billing_suburb").val('LPN');
        jQuery('#billing_postcode').val('0133');
    } else if (complex_name == 'eldin') {
        jQuery("#billing_suburb").val('STK');
        jQuery('#billing_postcode').val('2147');
        jQuery("#billing_complex_address").val('Lion St');
    } else if (complex_name == 'elm') {
        jQuery("#billing_suburb").val('ELD');
        jQuery('#billing_postcode').val('0147');
        jQuery("#billing_complex_address").val('Lor Ave');
    }
}
jQuery(document).on('change', '#billing_complex_name', function () {
    var getname = jQuery('#billing_complex_name').val();
    jQuery("#billing_suburb, #billing_postcode, #billing_complex_address").val('')// first reset
    myFunc(getname);
});

jQuery(document).on('mouseenter', '#billing_complex_name', function () {
    $(this).val(''); // need to reset after change 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="billing_complex_name">
    <option value="" selected>---</option>
    <option value="eldogleneast">eldogleneast</option>
    <option value="Reldoglen">Reldoglen</option>
    <option value="eldin">eldin</option>
    <option value="elm">elm</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<label>Suburb</label><br>
<input type="text" id="billing_suburb">
<br><br>
<label>Post Code</label><br>
<input type="text" id="billing_postcode">
<br><br>
<label>Address</label><br>
<input type="text" id="billing_complex_address">
```